# RecyclerView: why in landscape elements beyond the right edge of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

There is a problem when using RecyclerView. When you change the orientation to landscape, I put the number of columns = 2. But right column gets out off-screen. I do not know what the problem could be created like this Holder

```
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType)
        {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
```

Item layout

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
......
</FrameLayout>
```

RecyclerView init

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(getColumnCount(),  StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    adapter.setSelectionListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

**UPD**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include the layout that the RecyclerView is in? Looks like an issue with going underneath the navigation bar.

Comment: I mean the right edge

Answer (score 0):

I think so you should add this command to your `AppTheme`:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```